# Converting unary string of units to binary string only works once (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, string, integer, converters

I built an integer conversation from unary string of units = '1' to a binary representation in string format!

The function only works once and is limited to the number 31
here is my approach in javascript - can you help or explain?

```
func_unary_to_digit = function(p_reg1) {
    var grouper = {
       group:''
    };
    var unit = '1';
    var p_sys = 2;
    var i_grp = 0;
    var t1_reg = p_reg1;

    var lw1_unary = '';
    var rw1_unary = '';
    var lw2_unary = '0';
    var rw2_unary = '';

    for(it_g = 0; it_g < p_sys; it_g++) {
        grouper.group += unit;
    }
    if(p_reg1.length === 1) {
        lw1_unary = '';
        rw1_unary = unit;
    } else {
        for (it_s = 0; it_s <= t1_reg.length; it_s++) {
            lw1_unary = '';
            i_grp = 0;
            for (it_c = 0; it_c < t1_reg.length; it_c++) {
                if (it_c % grouper.group.length === 1) {
                    lw1_unary += unit;
                    i_grp++;
                }
            }
            if (t1_reg.length % grouper.group.length === 0) {
                //rw1_unary += inf;
                rw1_unary += '0';
            }
            if (t1_reg.length % grouper.group.length === 1) {
                rw1_unary += unit;
            }
            if (lw1_unary.length === 1) {
                lw1_unary = '';
                rw1_unary += unit;
            }
            t1_reg = lw1_unary;
        }
    }
    rw1_unary = rw1_unary.split('').reverse().join('');
    console.log(rw1_unary);
}
```

Comment: what is the expected result for `111111` (6 times 1)?

Comment: the result is '110'

Comment: [SOLVED] i tried in other version of Chrome and javascript parser is working correct pardon me!